# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '50' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in

Tags: php

After the host update my WordPress, the website showing this, I am not a programmer so I really don't know how to fix this, please someone can help~
the error is

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '50' (T_LNUMBER), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/travelac/public_html/wp-content/themes/entrada-child/functions.php on line 57

And the code around there is:

```
function entrada_truncate( $input, $maxWords, $maxChars ) {
    //  $content = mb_strimwidth( $input, 0, 50, '...' );
    wp_html_excerpt( $input, $50 );
    return $content ;
}
```

Line 57 is

```
wp_html_excerpt( $input, $50 );
```

Comment: `$50` is what? Fifty dollars?

Comment: Variables may not start with integers. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php - If you want the value `$50` (fifty dollas), use `'$50'` (quoted). If its supposed to be the integer 50, use just 50 without any identifier in front.

Comment: I just try 50 or '$50',but still not working ~

Comment: what else I can do ~

Comment: Read and inwardly digest @Quirel comment.

Comment: I tried, but not working~

Comment: according to manaual(https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_html_excerpt) `50` should work just fine

Comment: I comment out this whole function，now it is working. But I worry about if it may cause another problem.....